# Qute -- Worthy or what's its analogue?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

Friends, I wanted to use [Qute](http://www.inkcode.net/qute) on my Ubuntu 12.04. There are a couple of problems:

1. It relies on a [dead project](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/chromeless/).
2. One has to compile the files there.

The question now is: is it worth the pain to install this thingy?

If the answer to the previous question is no, then what is an alternative?

For one, I was suggested that `retext` might be a good option, if I wanted Markdown. But, the TeX support in `retext` does not sound great.

Please help me.